# How to have deletion of a object propagated or detected?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a vector of pointers to other "objects" in a class.

Is there any way, after/when one of those objects gets deleted to remove any pointer that might have been pointing to it from the vector?

The best thing would be to propagate the deletion somehow but, it would also be okay to just know an object has been deleted whenever the vector gets traversed.

Comment: Look at smart pointers [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

Comment: smart pointers perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use vanilla pointers. Use the classes [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and [`std::weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) instead.

These classes implement automatic memory management. When you don't need an object anymore, you don't delete the object, you delete all the `shared_ptr`s which reference that object. Only when no `shared_ptr`s to an object exist anymore, the actual object will get deleted.

Any `weak_ptr`s which still exist will return an object which will evaluate as `false`. When that happens, you know the `weak_ptr` can be removed from the vector.

Answer (score 1):

That's why `std::weak_ptr` exists. It doesn't stop deletion, but it does detect it.